# Answers package modification

Tags: answers, xpatch

I'm using answers package and 2 levels of enumerate environment. Sample:

1. (a) Excercise 1a

   (b) Excercise 1b
2. (a) Excercise 2a

   (b) Excercise 2b

Inside the answers file I want to get the first level number only for the first instance like this:

Answers:

1. (a) answer 1a;

   (b) answer 1b.
2. (a) answer 2a;

   (b) answer 2b.

Is there any possibility to modify the package to get this result?

Here is my .tex file.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, openany]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{answers}
\begin{document}

\Newassociation{otv}{Otvet}{ans}
\renewcommand{\Otvetlabel}[1]{#1}
\renewenvironment{Otvet}[1]{\textbf{#1}}{}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}[\jobname.ans]

\begin{enumerate}
\item 
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Excercise 1a
    \begin{otv}
    answer 1a    \end{otv}
  \item Excercise 1b
    \begin{otv}
    answer 1b    \end{otv}
  \end{enumerate}
\item 
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Excercise 2a
    \begin{otv}
    answer 2a   \end{otv}
  \item Excercise 2b
    \begin{otv}
    answer 2b    \end{otv}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\Closesolutionfile{ans}

Answers:

\input{\jobname.ans}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why don't you put the second level of enumeration inside minipages?  I believe the remaining width is \linewidth minus \labelwidth and \labelsep.

Comment: Looking at the answers manual, it appears that this package is only concerned with file I/O.  Formatting is an independent problem.

Comment: Okay, I see what you are getting at.  Answer is automatically including \theitem, which is currently defined at 1a, 1b, etc.

Comment: The actual line of code used to create the answer index is \item[\hskip\itemsep{\@nameuse{#1label}{##1}}]}% where #1 is Otvet in this case.

Comment: I was thinking if it is possible to add conditions on \Currentlabel in order to get needed 2nd level labels.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to add

```
\renewcommand{\Otvetparams}{\ifnum\value{enumii}=1{\arabic{enumi} (a)}%
\else{(\alph{enumii})}\fi}
```

with the other \renewcommands to get

[image: answers]

Sorry for confusing the issue with my half-baked comments, but it was rather obscure.

Comment: Thank you, but the issue is to write the first level number only once. 
Like this:
1 (a) answer (b) answer
2 (a) answer (b) answer

Comment: I have revised the solution per request.